# How to create Report in Openerp

Tags: xml, odoo

I finished a module in openerp 7 and I want to create a report like the picture in link below, to one of my class, how can I make it like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using webkit? If you know html it will be the easiest approach.

You need to ensure that you have installed the webkit reporting engine and you have installed wkhtmltopdf

Take a look at this link https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-do-i-start-using-webkit-reports-33117